# Tensorflow 2 eager vs graph mode

Tags: tensorflow

I've been working through the tensorflow-2.0.0 beta tutorials. In the  [advanced](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/quickstart/advanced.ipynb) example a `tensorflow.keras` subclass is used. The presence of the `@tf.function` decorator on `train_step` and `test_step` means the model executes in `graph` mode (not sure if that's the correct terminology, I mean oposite to `eager` mode). If I remove these decorators I can single step right into the model `call` function and see the input/output tensor for each layer which is neat.

My question is, is there a programatic way to enable/disable the `@tf.function` decorators. Commenting them out to switch between eager and graph mode doesn't seem particularly scaleable but it's certainly useful for debugging/learning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always write **two functions** (one with the decorator and one without) and call whichever suits you...

For example

```py
@tf.function()
def graph_function()
    # This function will operate in graph mode
    ...

def eager_function()
    # This function will operate in eager mode
   ...

if tf.executing_eagerly()
    my_function = eager_function
else:
    my_function = graph_function

# You proceed to my_function from now on
```

I don't know if there is a better way but I've seen this a lot being used in the tensorflow official repository on github.

Comment: Thanks, I guess you could make it a bit cleaner by creating a factory method which returns either function.

Comment: Yeah, true. Tensorflow typically has different modules altogether for eager and graph modes, but I think that's mostly because different people work on each.

Comment: I just found a recomendation to not decorate every function with @tf.function, rather just for example decorate a `train_one_step` and it'll inherit. So I guess that's not so bad, can create a debug and normal version

Answer (score 2):

I do not know in which version of Tensorflow it was introduced, but at least in TF 2.1, there is

```
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

available. It makes all `@tf.function`-decorated functions run in eager mode anyway, until this is reset by calling with argument `False` again.

For details see [Tensorflow experimental_run_functions_eagerly documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental_run_functions_eagerly).